# Started learning c but don't know why we are using Return 0

Tags: c

I started studying c programing.while learning some basic programs I got a doubt that why we r using "return 0" at the end of the program even if I am not writing that return 0 also I am getting correct outputs ( for basic programs).
I want to know...
1) what is the need of using?
2)if we won't write what will happend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 0):

Most function that you have in a c program has a return type. and by return type i mean some data to send back to something that has called that function. this caller can be another function, or even the operating system.

now when you write a c program yo would notice it has a main() function, inside which resides the code that one has written. this main function is described something like this

```
int main()
```

or

```
void main()
```

in this declaration, you can notice the `int` (for integer) and `void` for, well nothing. this defines what type of data the function would return.

so at the end of every c program the `return 0` is like a command saying to return the integer 0 to the caller (in this case the C runtime). there are a predefined integers which has a predefined meaning. like here `0` means executed without any error. usually returning 1 means the program executed with some error.

Comment: Also, *not* returning anything to the operating system with `void main` is actually not an option. A program will *always* return a value.